# Print the American Flag!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Special [Independence Day (USA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(United_States)) themed challenge for you today. You must write a program that prints this ascii-art representation of The American Flag.

```
0
|---------------------------------------------------------
| *   *   *   *   *   * #################################|
|   *   *   *   *   *                                    |
| *   *   *   *   *   *                                  |
|   *   *   *   *   *   #################################|
| *   *   *   *   *   *                                  |
|   *   *   *   *   *                                    |
| *   *   *   *   *   * #################################|
|   *   *   *   *   *                                    |
| *   *   *   *   *   *                                  |
|########################################################|
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|########################################################|
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|########################################################|
|                                                        |
|                                                        |
|########################################################|
|---------------------------------------------------------
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

Trailing spaces on each line, as well as one trailing newline, are allowed.

Note that this isn't quite the way the flag should look, but it's the closest I could get with ASCII.

As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so standard loopholes apply and shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Is trailing whitespace allowed?

Comment: @Dennis as long as it's not excessive I don't see why not. So one trailing newline is OK.

Comment: What about trailing spaces on the individual lines?

Comment: @Dennis yeah, that's fine.

Comment: I would make this a pop-contest and see who prints the most realistic flag.

Comment: @Hosch250 That would end up closed as "art contest"

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the rules about that changed since I was here.

Comment: @Hosch250 the full correct spec of the flag is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_States . You can't get more realistic than that. It might be worth asking as a codegolf next 4th of July . As far as I can tell it's never been asked.  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28784/15599 is the closest I could find. An interesting difference between this challenge and the real flag is that the stars area should reach as far as the bottom of the 7th stripe (red) but I don't think it would have been very visually appealing in ASCII art.

Comment: @steveverrill Yes, but we could draw a flag rippling in the breeze, perhaps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## CJam, <s>184</s> <s>120</s> <s>109</s> <s>101</s> <s>76</s> <s>74</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 58 bytes

```
0'-57*"  #"56f*'|f+7*2>" *  "50*22/W<Sf+..e&~J$]N'|+a37*.+
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0'-57*%22%20%20%23%2256f*'%7Cf%2B7*2%3E%22%20*%20%20%2250*22%2FW%3CSf%2B..e%26~J%24%5DN'%7C%2Ba37*.%2B).

#### Idea

The most interesting part of the flag is the stars and stripes pattern.

If we repeat two spaces and a number sign 56 times and append a vertical bar to each, we get

```
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
```

Repeating this pattern 7 times and discarding the first two lines, we obtain the stripes:

```
#########################################################|
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
                                                         |
                                                         |
#########################################################|
```

Now, if we repeat the string `" *  "` 50 times and split the result into chunks of length 22, we obtain the stars:

```
 *   *   *   *   *   *
   *   *   *   *   *  
 *   *   *   *   *   *
   *   *   *   *   *  
 *   *   *   *   *   *
   *   *   *   *   *  
 *   *   *   *   *   *
   *   *   *   *   *  
 *   *   *   *   *   *
```

The whitespace is a little off, but we can fix that by eliminating the last chunk and appending a space to the remaining ones.

Now, if we superimpose stripes and stars, we get

```
 *   *   *   *   *   * #################################|
   *   *   *   *   *                                    |
 *   *   *   *   *   *                                  |
   *   *   *   *   *   #################################|
 *   *   *   *   *   *                                  |
   *   *   *   *   *                                    |
 *   *   *   *   *   * #################################|
   *   *   *   *   *                                    |
 *   *   *   *   *   *                                  |
########################################################|
                                                        |
                                                        |
########################################################|
                                                        |
                                                        |
########################################################|
                                                        |
                                                        |
########################################################|
```

All that's left to do is adding two lines of 57 dashes, adding a column of 37 vertical bars and putting the cherry on top.

#### Code

```
0         e# Push a zero.
'-57*     e# Push a string of 57 dashes.
"  #"56f* e# Repeat each character in the string 56 times.
'|f+      e# Append a vertical bar to each resulting string.
7*        e# Repeat the resulting array of strings 7 times.
2>        e# Discard the first two strings.
" *  "50* e# Repeat the string 50 times.
22/       e# Split the result into chunks of length 22.
W<        e# Discard the last, partial chunk.
Sf*       e# Append a space to each chunk.
..e&      e# Twofold vectorized logical AND.
          e# Since all characters in the strings are truthy, this always selects
          e# the second character, painting the stars over the stripes.
~         e# Dump all resulting strings on the stack.
J$        e# Copy the string of dashes.

]         e# Wrap the entire stack in an array.
N'|+a37*  e# Repeat ["\n|"] 37 times.
.+        e# Perform vectorized concatenation.
```

Comment: For a very short, magic moment I was beating you

Comment: It ain't every day you see someone write a CJam program 120 bytes too long.

Comment: What I like best is how you found a way to have 6 stars on each line, then naturally get rid of the ones you didn't want.

Comment: @steveverrill: I liked that too, but I found something shorter...

Comment: Cool! (You did something similar with the honeycomb didn't you?) But now you need to revise the superimposed image in your explanation.

Comment: @steveverrill: Oh, thanks! Yes, you're right, I did almost exactly the same with the honeycomb. I actually saw that answer a few hours ago when I posted a long overdue [tip on ASCII art with CJam](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52627). That's probably why it occurred to me.

Answer (score 27):

## Python 2, 113 bytes

```py
for i in range(38):print i and"|"+["-"*57,(" *  "*7)[i%2*2:][:(i<11)*23].ljust(56,"  #"[i%3])+"|"][1<i<21]*(i<22)
```

String slicing and modulo checks galore.

Comment: +1 Very impressive, 7 bytes ahead of my ruby answer. Both you and EDC65 were ahead of Dennis at one time? wow!

Comment: A python answer that is competing with a cjam answer. What a time to be alive!

Comment: I like how the value `i=0` is itself being printed.

Answer (score 9):

## Brainf**k, <strike>3355</strike> <strike>3113</strike> <strike>1598</strike> <strike>1178</strike> 782 bytes

[What is this language?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

Here is the hand optimized version featuring 28 loops.  I think I've taken this about as far as it will go.

Here's the run at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/1koQFX):

```
+++[>++++<-]>[>+++>+++>+++>++++++++++>+>++++<<<<<<-]>++++++>---->->>>.<--.
<++++.>>---.>+++++++[<........>-]<<.
<.<<<<+++++[>>.<.>..<<-]>>.<.>.<<++++[>>>........<<<-]>>>.>.>.
<.<<<<+++++[>>...<.<-]+++++[>>.......<<-]>>.>>.>.
<.<<<<++++++[>>.<.>..<<-]++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
<.<<...<<+++++[>.>...<<-]++++[>>>........<<<-]>>>.>.>.
<.<<<<++++++[>>.<.>..<<-]++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
<.<<<<+++++[>>...<.<-]+++++[>>.......<<-]>>.>>.>.
<.<<<<+++++[>>.<.>..<<-]>>.<.>.<<++++[>>>........<<<-]>>>.>.>.
<.<<<<+++++[>>...<.<-]+++++[>>.......<<-]>>.>>.>.
<.<<<<++++++[>>.<.>..<<-]++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
>>>+++[<<<
<.>>>+++++++[<<<<........>>>>-]<<<.>.
>>++[<<
<.<<<<+++++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
>>-]<<
>>>-]<<<
<.>>>+++++++[<<<<........>>>>-]<<<.>.
<.>>.>+++++++[<........>-]<<.
>>++++++++[<<<.>.<.>.>>-]
```

---

### How does this work?

```
 1: +++[>++++<-]>[>+++>+++>+++>++++++++++>+>++++<<<<<<-]>++++++>---->->>>.<--.
 2: <++++.>>---.>+++++++[<........>-]<<.
 3: <.<<<<+++++[>>.<.>..<<-]>>.<.>.<<++++[>>>........<<<-]>>>.>.>.
 4: <.<<<<+++++[>>...<.<-]+++++[>>.......<<-]>>.>>.>.
 5: <.<<<<++++++[>>.<.>..<<-]++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
 6: <.<<...<<+++++[>.>...<<-]++++[>>>........<<<-]>>>.>.>.
 7: <.<<<<++++++[>>.<.>..<<-]++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
 8: <.<<<<+++++[>>...<.<-]+++++[>>.......<<-]>>.>>.>.
 9: <.<<<<+++++[>>.<.>..<<-]>>.<.>.<<++++[>>>........<<<-]>>>.>.>.
10: <.<<<<+++++[>>...<.<-]+++++[>>.......<<-]>>.>>.>.
11: <.<<<<++++++[>>.<.>..<<-]++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
12: >>>+++[<<<
13: <.>>>+++++++[<<<<........>>>>-]<<<.>.
14: >>++[<<
15: <.<<<<+++++++[>>........<<-]>>>>.>.
16: >>-]<<
17: >>>-]<<<
18: <.>>>+++++++[<<<<........>>>>-]<<<.>.
19: <.>>.>+++++++[<........>-]<<.
20: >>++++++++[<<<.>.<.>.>>-]
```

This program uses 10 memory locations:

```
0: loop counter #1
1: loop counter #2
2: "*"  ASCII 42
3: spc  ASCII 32
4: "#"  ASCII 35
5: "|"  ASCII 124
6: "\n" ASCII 10
7: "0"  ASCII 48, "-"  ASCII 45
8: loop counter #3
9: loop counter #4
```

#### Line 1

- This line sets up the ASCII characters in registers 2 through 7 (mostly).  Some tweaking is done later.
- This code first puts 3 in register 0, and then loops 3 times incrementing register 1 four times each loop: `+++[>++++<-]`.  Then end result is that register 0 is 0, and register 1 is 12.
- The 12 is used as the loop counter for the next loop.  For 12 times through the loop, registers 2, 3, and 4 are incremented 3 times, register 5 is incremented 10 times, register 6 is incremented 1 time, and register 7 is incremented 4 times.  At the end of this loop, they contain: R2(36), R3(36), R4(36), R5(120), R6(12), R7(48).  After the loop register 2 is incremented 6 times, register 3 is decremented 4 times, and register 4 is decremented once.  At this point, the values are: R2(42), R3(32), R4(35), R5(120), R6(12), R7(48).  All but registers 5 and 6 contain their initial ASCII values.
- Next register 7 is output, the `"0"` at the top of the flag!
- Next register 6 is decremented twice to 10 (ASCII newline) and output.  Done with the first line of the flag!

#### Line 2

- First it increments register 5 by 4 which makes it `"|"` (ASCII 124) and outputs it.
- Then it decrements register 7 by three changing it from `"0"` (ASCII 48) into `"-"` (ASCII 45) and outputs it.
- Next it puts 7 into loop counter 3 (register 8) and loops 7 times, writing out 8 dashes each time for a total of 7*8 = 56 dashes.
- Finally it ends by outputting a newline.

#### Line 3

- This line contains two loops.
- The first loop writes `" *  "` 5 times.
- Then `" * "` is written
- The second loop loops 4 times writing 8 `"#"` for a total of 32.
- Then `"#"`, `"|"`, and `"\n"` are written.

#### Lines 4 - 11

- These lines use the same technique as line 3 to write out the stars and stripes of the flag.

#### Line 12

- This line starts a loop that runs 3 times.
- The loop ends at line 17.

#### Line 13

- Writes a strip that goes across the flag.
- Uses a loop that runs 7 times writing `"#"` 8 times each time through the loop.

#### Line 14

- The start of a loop that runs 2 times.

#### Line 15

- Writes a strip that goes across the flag.
- Uses a loop that runs 7 times writing `" "` 8 times each time through the loop.

#### Line 16

- End of inner loop that started at line 14.

#### Line 17

- End of outer loop that started at line 13.

#### Line 18

- Draws bottom stripe of flag.

#### Line 19

- Draws bottom border of flag.

#### Line 20

- Draws the flagpole.
- Loops 8 times, writing `"|"` and newline twice each time through the loop.

Comment: You actually managed to compress the flag! I hope you'll post an explanation when you're done golfing. I'd very much like to know how this works.

Comment: I will post an explanation. I'm still golfing!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (*ES6*), 153 <s>156</s>

Using template string, there is 1 newline that is significant and counted

Test running the snippet below (being EcmaScript 6, Firefox only)

```js
// TEST - Just for testing purpose,redefine console.log

console.log = (...x) => O.innerHTML += x+'\n'

// SOLUTION

o=[0];for(o[r=1]=o[21]='-'[R='repeat'](57);++r<21;o[r]=" *  "[R](7).substr(r%2*2,r<11&&23)+'  #'[r%3][R](r<11?33:56)+'|')o[37]='';console.log(o.join`
|`)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

To be even more patriotic, here is the EcmaScript 5 version

```js
// TEST - Just for testing purpose,redfine console.log

console.log = function(x){ O.innerHTML += x+'\n' }

// SOLUTION - 175 bytes

for(o=(A=Array)(38),o[0]=0,r=2;r<21;r++)o[r]=A(8)[J='join'](" *  ").substr((r&1)*2,r<11?23:0)+A(r<11?34:57)[J]('  #'[r%3])+'|';
o[1]=o[r]=A(58)[J]('-'),console.log(o[J]('\n|'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: +1 for calling ES5 *more patriotic*

Answer (score 7):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////): 225 characters

```
/D/ddd//d/--------//H/hhh//h/########//S/sss//s/        //A/aaaaa//a/ *  //b/|HHh|
|SSs|
|SSs|
//p/|
|
|
|
/0
|DDd-
|A * Hh#|
|  A Ss |
|A * Ss |
|  A Hh#|
|A * Ss |
|  A Ss |
|A * Hh#|
|  A Ss |
|A * Ss |
bbb|HHh|
|DDd-
pppp
```

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <s>104</s> 102 bytes

Using ideas from ManAtWork's Ruby answer with permission.

```
puts 0,s=?|+?-*57,(0..18).map{|i|?|+("#  "[i%3]*(i>8?56:33)).rjust(56," *   *"[i%2*2,4])+?|},s,'|
'*16
```

## Ruby, <s>127 121</s> 112 bytes

Changed quotes to `?` used array instead of conditional for stripe colour. used conditional instead of formula for stripe length.

```
puts 0,s=?|+?-*57
19.times{|i|puts ?|+("#  "[i%3]*(i>8?56:33)).rjust(56,i%2>0?"   *":" *  ")+?|}
puts s,"|\n"*16
```

The trick here is to draw the stripes (both red/`#` and white/`space`) to the correct length, then right justify them, padding with stars. Ruby's `rjust` allows us to specify the padding string, which alternates between `" *  "` and `"   *"`.

**Original version, 127 bytes**

```
puts 0,s="|"+"-"*57
19.times{|i|puts("|"+((i%3>0?" ":"#")*((i+1)/10*23+33)).rjust(56,i%2>0?"   *":" *  ")+"|")}
puts s,"|\n"*16
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to reload the page before checking whether a Ruby answer already exists. As [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52625) is not significantly different, I deleted it. Feel free to use any good part you may find in it.

Comment: @manatwork I don't see that you needed to delete it, it was shorter than mine and I'd already upvoted it. There were some Ruby tricks in there I didn't know, I'm new to ruby. I'm down to 104 using the best of both answers, which is the shortest answer in a conventional language.  I don't understand why I can use the `map` in the middle of the `puts`  but I can't use it on its own, even if i surround it with brackets: `puts((0.18).map{})`. If you see any further improvements either let me know, or undelete your own answer and post it there.

Comment: I'm impressed that Ruby `rjust` can take a string and not just a char. Too bad Python can't do that...

Answer (score 3):

## SWI-Prolog, 275 bytes

In a language of French origin, which is *kind of* fitting

```
a:-put(48),nl,b,c(0).
b:-z,w(-,57).
c(I):-nl,I=36;J is I+1,(I=19,b,c(J);I>19,z,c(J);I>8,z,(I mod 3=:=0,w(#,56);tab(56)),z,c(J);z,(I mod 2=:=0,tab(1),w('*   ',5),put(42),tab(1);w('   *',5),tab(3)),(0=:=I mod 3,w(#,33);tab(33)),z,c(J)).
z:-put(124).
w(A,B):-writef('%r',[A,B]).
```

See the result [here](https://ideone.com/hDERz8)

Comment: I hate to break an existing answer, but the first version had 11 stripes instead of 13. I didn't change anything else. You can check the edit history to see what I changed. Sorry about that.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Fixed, only needed to change two numbers and didnt change the length of the answer, so it's all good

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>235</strike> <strike>211</strike> <strike>208</strike> <strike>205</strike> <strike>203</strike> <strike>198</strike> <strike>197</strike> 186 bytes

```
i;x(){for(puts("0");i<37;i++){char b[58]="";i<21?memset(b,i%20?i%3&1?35:32:45,56),i&&i<10?memcpy(b," *   *   *   *   *   *   "+(i%2?0:2),23):0,b[56]=i%20?124:45:0;printf("|%.57s\n",b);}}
```

edit: added some of Cool Guy's suggestions and made use of ?: to replace some if statements.

edit: removed overflow \0 prevention and used string length limiter in printf instead.

edit: reworked both memset conditionals.

edit: moved puts("0") inside the for header to remove its semicolon.

edit: slight refactoring to get 11 more bytes.

Comment: Good first attempt. But this does not seem to print the `|` at the start of **every** line...

Comment: Your code in 198 bytes:`i;c(){puts("0");for(;i<37;i++){char b[58]="|";if(i<21){memset(b,!((i-1)%3)?35:32,56);if(i<10)memcpy(b," *   *   *   *   *   *   "+((i%2)?0:2),23);b[56]='|';}if(!i||i==20){memset(b,45,57);}puts(b);}}`

Comment: @Cool Guy: Thanks for the catch. I forgot to move the '|' back to the second printf from the initializer. I tried running your code using GCC under Cygwin, but the formatting is off. Is there anything special I need to do to run it or any flags needed at compile time?

Comment: No special flags required. [Test it here](http://rextester.com/SJTYAJ25185) Golf it more by using `45` instead of `'-'` and `35` instead of `'#'` and `32` instead of `' '`

Comment: @Cool Guy: Good suggestion on the character encoding values. And good catch on the i==0 I overlooked. I think your initial code wasn't working because of the second puts(), but that was partially my fault because by forgetting to change the "|"'s position back, it made it seem like the buffer contained the entire string. The code in the link you provided using the printf at the end does work now.

Comment: You're welcome. You might find [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c) helpful. :-)